# Can not properly use BufferedReader class

Tags: java, keyboard, bufferedreader

Hi I'm using eclipse and I work on windows 7 system.
I would like to read some characters form keyboard using BufferedReader class.
I'm using that code in Thread class:

```
public void run()
{
    int ch;
    while(!done)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            ch = keyboard.read();
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("petla");
    }
}
```

The problem is that after I run the thread(It enters to the loop) and I press some buttons and confirm that using enter(\n) nothing has happen. Please help

Comment: Looks like the problem is not in this code part.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Looks like it is to me.

Comment: At least close the stream after using it!

Answer (score 1):

You are losing buffered data. Don't keep creating a new `BufferedReader` for every character. Use the same one created before the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right but it is not the point. I forgot to add that it is Swing application. It is possible using this class with window app?

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what the problem is. I was thought that when i press sign it will be buffered immediately but i have to write it to the console. I need to read pressed buttons not entered in consol. Somebody adviced me to initialize JTextField for example and read sign using that on focus. But is it elegant resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to precise my problem. I have a window app which looks like that:
http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/5859/scaning.jpg
I need press some buttons(not being focused in a JTextField) and on that basis add some position to the JTable. But while I have opened my app I can't put signs to the console. It is very simple. I just want to open my full screen program, type some characters and on that basis add position to JTable. I can't make it more clear. Thx for respond.